# to check highcharts values using selenium and firefox

Tags: java, firefox, highcharts, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the following java class to do some automated testing in my Highcharts graphs in firefox browser
(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.)
I would like to know how we can what are the values in categories(i.e. xaxis) and the yaxis values. Seem to run into problems using

```
List<WebElement> gClassElements driver.findElementsByClassName("highcharts-data-labels highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker");
```

or would it be better to search for some combination of tags? The highcharts code looks like

```
<pre>
<!-- g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="6" transform="translate(58,55) scale(1 1)" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <g zIndex="1" style="cursor:default;" transform="translate(126,185)" visibility="inherit">
        <text x="3" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#2f7ed8;line-height:14px;fill:#2f7ed8;" zIndex="1">
            <tspan x="3">4</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
    <g zIndex="1" style="cursor:default;" transform="translate(388,44)" visibility="inherit">
        <text x="3" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#2f7ed8;line-height:14px;fill:#2f7ed8;" zIndex="1">
            <tspan x="3">15</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</g -->
</pre>
```

Comment: the html code does not seem to be coming up it is only displaying 4 and 15> And not the html surrounding it. here is the code link. http://jsfiddle.net/6amxs/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this java library written to make highchart testing easier;

https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey/tree/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/selenium/graphs